# HTML form not posting or taking any action on submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post, submit

For some reason, the following form will not make a post request when it gets submitted:

```
<form action="/join" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="scenario" value="hospital">Hospital Patient Scenario</input><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Join Game"/>
</form>
```

This form; however, is in the same project, and it works:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Why is the first form not making a post request on submit?

To provide more detail, the routes /login and /join are defined in two separate routes documents that are both required by the server. I tried moving the /join route to the routes document with the /login route and it still didn't work.

Comment: have you checked browser network tab? is any request getting fired?

Comment: in the first form, value should be 'submit', I think

Comment: How do you know the post request is not submitted?

Comment: @Paritosh, I know the post request isn't being submitted because the network tab in the browser isn't firing a request, and it also isn't registering on my server side

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though another form or perhaps another script I was using was interfering with the form's post request. I have removed that code, and I'll be debugging by trying to see which part of my other code interferes.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you should replace:

```
<input type="submit" value="Join Game"/>
```

by:

```
<button name="my-button" id="my-button" >Submit</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<form action="/join" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="scenario" value="hospital">Hospital Patient 
 Scenario</input><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="Join Game"/>
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work still. The network tracker for chrome still doesn't register a post request going through with this code and neither does my server. I can provide more detail on the context of these requests if you think it would be helpful.